# App Engine "NeedIndexError: no matching index found" does not occur on development server but does on production

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Python app engine app that works fine on the development server, but does not work after I upload it on the actual appspot.com server.

It seems that missing composite indexes does not produce `no matching index found` errors on development server. Is it possible to raise that error as well on development server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely: you just need to start the devappserver with [`--require_indexes=yes`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#--require_indexesyesno).

Note however that the devserver should be creating those indexes in index.yaml for you anyway (and this switch will actually disable that behaviour). You may need to ensure you deploy changes to that file along with the rest of your code.

Comment: I have disabled the AUTOGENERATED flag in index.yaml. So the indexes have never been generated automatically any more for me. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: For some reason I am running into this same problem times and times again. EVen though I have specified that stuff in index.yaml, and it always happens in production, never in dev. Something's just not right.